# I am trying to compile my jnicode it showing error _JNIEnv::GetShortArrayElements(JNIEnv*&, _jshortArray*&, int)'

Tags: android, c++, ubuntu, opus

I am trying to compile my jnicode it showing error

```
_JNIEnv::GetShortArrayElements(JNIEnv*&, _jshortArray*&, int)'
```

my code is:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint Java_com_techgentsia_sound_Opusmain_nativeDecodeBytes (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jbyteArray decoder_insrc,jshortArray decoder_out)
{
    int frame_size=320;

    jshort* pcm_data_decoder=env->GetShortArrayElements(env, decoder_out,0);

    jbyte* opus_data_decoder=env->GetByteArrayElements(env, decoder_insrc,0);  
}
```

the error in compiler is:

```
/home/clifford/opusbuild/jni/opus/com_techgentsia_sound_Opusmain.cpp:117:72: error: no matching function for call to '_JNIEnv::GetShortArrayElements(JNIEnv*&, _jshortArray*&, int)'
/home/clifford/opusbuild/jni/opus/com_techgentsia_sound_Opusmain.cpp:117:72: note: candidate is:
/home/clifford/apps/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include    /jni.h:921:13: note: jshort* _JNIEnv::GetShortArrayElements(jshortArray, jboolean*)
/home/clifford/apps/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:921:13: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem change the code as below.

```
                                                                                                                          extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint Java_com_techgentsia_sound_Opusmain_nativeDecodeBytes (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jbyteArray decoder_insrc,jshortArray decoder_out)
```

{
    int frame_size=320;

```
jshort* pcm_data_decoder=env->GetShortArrayElements( decoder_out,0);

jbyte* opus_data_decoder=env->GetByteArrayElements( decoder_insrc,0);
```

}

we don'need to pass env in this methods
 GetShortArrayElements( decoder_out,0);
 GetByteArrayElements( decoder_insrc,0);
because i am writing cpp class